# Onclick Move Element To First Position

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make it so that when clicked, that element is moved to the first position in the "news-layout-1" element. So far, I haven't been able to get it to work. The actual script I'm trying to do this with is an RSS feed, so I am unable to add individual class names.

```
<div class="news-layout-1">
  <div class="item-post"><h1 class="item-title">First One</h1></div>
  <div class="item-post"><h1 class="item-title">Second One</h1></div>
  <div class="item-post"><h1 class="item-title">Third One</h1></div>
  <div class="item-post"><h1 class="item-title">Fourth One</h1></div>
  <div class="item-post"><h1 class="item-title">Fifth One</h1></div>
</div>

$(".item-post").click(function() {
    $($this).prependTo($(".item-post:first-of-type"));
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhav4co6/

Comment: do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/bhav4co6/1/

Comment: @Kartikeya yes. Thanks. Post it as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$(".item-post").click(function() {
    $('.news-layout-1').prepend($(this));
});
```

[Working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bhav4co6/1/)